# how to use a docker container kill [containerID] command to kill a container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm playing with docker software following this link: http://www.ruanyifeng.com/blog/2018/02/docker-tutorial.html. There are two points which confused me.

1: to avoid typing sudo each time, the author mentioned that can add the user into  Docker user group by the following command:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

I tried this in my computer, instead of using $USER, I use $myusername, my user name is my login user name in my computer. Then it failed... haha. I guess I need to use $USER instead.

2: I tried to run a ubuntu docker container with

```
$ sudo docker container run -it ubuntu bash
```

Then I do not know how to kill it.... haha... because I do not know the container ID and it seemed like I was in the ubuntu mode and can not get back. 
The following is the output.

```
:~$ sudo docker container run -it ubuntu bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
7ddbc47eeb70: Pull complete 
c1bbdc448b72: Pull complete 
8c3b70e39044: Pull complete 
45d437916d57: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6e9f67fa63b0323e9a1e587fd71c561ba48a034504fb804fd26fd8800039835d
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/# ls
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/# cd lib64
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/lib64# ls
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/lib64# cd ..
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/# cd home
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/home# ls
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/home# mkdir jack
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/home# ls
jack
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/home# cd ..
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/# cd sys
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/sys# ls
block  bus  class  dev  devices  firmware  fs  hypervisor  kernel  module  power
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/sys# cd kernel
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/sys/kernel# ls
boot_params  fscaps              kexec_crash_size  notes          security       uevent_seqnum
cgroup       iommu_groups        kexec_loaded      profiling      slab           vmcoreinfo
config       irq                 livepatch         rcu_expedited  tracing
debug        kexec_crash_loaded  mm                rcu_normal     uevent_helper
root@c3bfdf5922ea:/sys/kernel# cd
root@c3bfdf5922ea:~# sudo docker container kill 
bash: sudo: command not found
root@c3bfdf5922ea:~# sudo docker container kill 1
bash: sudo: command not found
root@c3bfdf5922ea:~# docker container kill 0
bash: docker: command not found
root@c3bfdf5922ea:~# sudo docker container kill 0
bash: sudo: command not found
root@c3bfdf5922ea:~# quit
bash: quit: command not found
root@c3bfdf5922ea:~# quit()
> 
> sudo docker container kill 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sudo'
```

**EDIT:** for question 2, I pressed control + d and accidentally get back to the original ubuntu terminal. Yeah. But still got no lucks when trying to kill the ubuntu container. The following is what I tried out.

```
root@c3bfdf5922ea:~# exit
:~$ docker container kill 0
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/0/kill?signal=KILL: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
:~$ sudo docker container kill 0
[sudo] password for devel: 
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 0: No such container: 0
:~$ sudo docker container kill 1
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 1: No such container: 1
:~$ sudo docker container kill 
"docker container kill" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker container kill --help'.

Usage:  docker container kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Kill one or more running containers
:~$ sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              775349758637        3 days ago          64.2MB
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        10 months ago       1.84kB
:~$ sudo docker container kill 775349758637
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 775349758637: No such container: 775349758637
```

**EDIT AGAIN**: for queston 1, I tried the command with $USER and it did not work. For question 2, I tried the command with sudo docker container ls -all, and I guess the number after root is the container ID, and tried again with no lucks.

```
:~$ sudo docker container ls -all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
c3bfdf5922ea        ubuntu              "bash"              33 minutes ago      Exited (0) 11 minutes ago                       adoring_villani
```

more trials:

```
:~$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
:~$ docker container run -it ubuntu bash
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
:~$ sudo docker container run -it ubuntu bash
root@ff9c3f3e1a2c:/# sudo docker container kill ff9c3f3e1a2c
bash: sudo: command not found
root@ff9c3f3e1a2c:/# docker container kill ff9c3f3e1a2c
bash: docker: command not found
root@ff9c3f3e1a2c:/#
```

Comment: One question at a time, please. Make it clear what is it that you're asking specifically. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image id isn't the same as the container id. Use the `docker ps` command to list containers:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
841eff335225        ubuntu              "bash"              4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                       myubuntu
```

(`-a` also lists exited containers)

In most docker commands you can use the id (`841eff335225`) or the name (`myubuntu`). The id itself is the beggining of the container "long id" (any length will do, but short lengths may be ambiguous, 6+ is usually enough).

You can assign a name (must be unique) to a container by using `--name <somename>` in the `docker run` command. Otherwise the container gets a random name (adjective+science/computer celebrity).

Notes

- The docker command should of course be used **outside** the container... so exit the container before killing it, or kill it from another terminal.
- `docker ps -q` returns just the ids, so this can be used to generate parameters to other Docker commands: `docker kill $(docker ps -q)` will kill all running containers.